# How to handle elements that fell through a filter when using Sequence in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I would like to filter a list and log the items which fell through the filter, similar to this:

```
val evenNumbers = (1..10)
            .filter { it % 2 == 0 }
            .onFallThrough { println("dropped $it") }  // wishful Kotlin
            .toList()
```

This should then lead to the following output:

```
dropped 1
dropped 3
dropped 5
dropped 7
dropped 9
```

as well as all even numbers collected in the list `evenNumbers`.

Looking through the manual page on [Sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/index.html), I couldn't find anything that seemed to do this. Is there a way to achieve this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [`partition`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html):

```
val evenNumbers = (1..10)
    .partition { it % 2 == 0 }
    .let {
        println("dropped ${it.second}")
        it.first
    }
```

It returns a `Pair` with its `first` property containing all elements that matched the condition and its `second` property containing the elements that did not match.

Comment: Just what I was going to suggest!  — If this were a common pattern, you could put that into your own partition function, taking as a first (optional) parameter a lambda to call with the dropped values.